# List of all users who subscribed for Laravel Cashier in given date range

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

There are many functions in Laravel Cashier to get a lot of subscription information for a particular user. What if I need to get the list of all users who have subscribed in a given date range or who have cancelled in a given date range.
User::subscription()->where doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can check subscriptions with the method `subscribed('packageName')`. Non tested I should be something like

`User::where('subscription', User::subscribed('packageName')->between('created_at', [$start, $end])->get()`

Comment: but subscribed is not a static method so the error is:
Non-static method App\\User::subscribed() should not be called statically

Comment: Try ```User::>has('subscription', function (Builder $q) {
    return $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
})->get();```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work and there is a typo.